# Textbox filled with Select value not working

Tags: jquery, forms

Found the perfect little script for my form. It adds the value of the select into a textbox.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
(window).load(function(){
$("select[name='type[]']").change(function() {
$("input[name='tvalue[]']").eq($(this).index()).val(this.value);
}).change();
});
/]]> 
</script>
```

Here's the rub.
Can someone explain why this works:

```
<select name="type[]">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
</select>

<select name="type[]">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="tvalue[]" id="tvalue[]" />
<input type="text" name="tvalue[]" id="tvalue[]" />
```

But, this doesn't? (Of course this is the layout I need.):

```
<select name="type[]">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="tvalue[]" id="tvalue[]" />

<select name="type[]">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="tvalue[]" id="tvalue[]" />
```

What's happening is, the first Select works, but the second one doesn't.

And if I add a third Select and Text, the second Select changes the third Text and the third Select does nothing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.each()`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("select[name='type[]']").each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            $("input[name='tvalue[]']").eq($(this).index()).val(this.value);
        }).change();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with the id's of your inputs.  They really should be unique, and I recall that brackets are a no-no as well.  I'm not sure why it works sometimes, in some layoutS.  I might speculate that the indexing gets reset in your second layout, whereas in the first it isn't - thus, your .eq() is able to find the second match in the first layout, but not the second.

A way to fix this? I would probably pair up the names of the associated select and input elements, and have all the selects share a class. Use that class in your top level selector, and use the name attribute of "this" to find the desired input element.